# lost my drivers loading windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

I need to load my drivers back on my computer.  Lost them loading windows 7.  Can the drivers be loaded on a blank DVD and then loaded on my computer?  Don't have a flash drive around.  Any other ideas.  Is there a way to use my second computer to help load the drives?

Comment: I will take help any way I can get it.

Comment: go to manufacture website and download all the drivers your need

Comment: @karenschultze, post your make and exact model of PC and we can help you find your drivers download page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can download the driver installers from any system connected to the internet and transfer them to the PC in question via any means, such as CD/DVD, USB drive, over the network (if networking at least is enabled) etc.

If you own a laptop or pre-built desktop you will be able to find all the drivers for supported OSes (such as Windows 7 32 and 64-bit) from the manufacturer's support site. Just search for your system model and locate the software/driver downloads page for it.

Windows Update might also install the relevant drivers for you, but they may be out of date so best to get them directly from the manufacturer's site.